Exercise on electromagnetic waves
I am trying to solve the following exercise on electromagnetic waves, taken from "Problems and solutions on Electromagnetism", by Lim, Yung-kuo. To determine which receiver picks up the greater signal, my idea was to determine the intensities of the "total wave" that reach the receivers. To calculate the intensity, I need the electric total electric field in $R_1$ and $R_2$; however, the text is specific neither about the direction of propagation of the waves generated by $A,B,C$ and $D$, nor (consequently) about the polarization of the waves; thus, I am not able to determine the total electric field in the two receivers.
In the solution proposed to this problem, the author calculates the total magnitude of the electric field (in $R1$ or in $R2$) as the algebraic sum of the magnitudes of the electric fields generated by the 4 sources. This would suggest that these electric fields lies on the same direction (because the magnitude of a sum is the sum of the magnitudes if and only if the vectors are parallel), but how can I deduce it?
Thanks for any answer and help

is this not just interference of unpolarized light?

The electric fields of electromagnetic radiation travelling towards R1 from A, B and C would necessarily be in the same plane perpendicular to the line joining them. That is because electromagnetic waves are transverse - the E-field is perpendicular to the wave motion. The same can be said of the waves reaching R2 from B and D.
However, nothing is said about the polarisation of the waves and so it cannot be concluded that the E-fields point in exactly the same (or opposing) directions. It is also not true, for arbitrary polarisations, that the E-field of waves reaching R1 from D can be in the same direction as waves reaching R1 from A, B or C. It is only true if the waves are all linearly polarised normally to the plane of the diagram. Ditto for waves reaching R2 from A and C for example.
The question states that the wave sources are "identical", which we might assume means they all emit waves with the same polarisation. However, that is not sufficient information. For example, if they were all emitting waves polarised in the plane of the diagram then the E-fields of waves arriving at R1 from sources A and D would not be aligned.
I suspect the question is missing a statement that all the waves are polarised normally to the plane of the diagram or you are invited to assume that "at great distances from B" means that any misalignment of the E-fields due to some other common polarisation state is small enough to ignore because you can assume the waves from ABCD are travelling along almost parallel paths when they reach R1 and R2.

But the direction of propagation of a wave is unique, or not? I mean, can the waves generated by B have different directions of propagation?

The question states that the transmitters are "identical". This implies they have the same polarization. Less obviously, it must also imply they are in phase with each other, because otherwise the question is unsolvable. (We might also have to assume the radiation patterns are isotropic, which doesn't seem to be stated at all)

@ThePhoton it isn't sufficient that they have the same polarisation. If they are polarised in the plane of the diagram then the electric fields don't simply add up at R1 and R2 from all the transmitters.

@Steppenwolf I cannot understand your comment.

@ProfRob I didn't say it was sufficient to know they have the same polarization. I said we also have to know (or make some inferences or assumptions about) their relative phases and if they are directional. Maybe there are other factors I didn't think of.

@ProfRob, I mean, what is the direction of the wave generated by B (if there is a way to know it, of course)?
